# Relax vertices in Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

Geometry nodes are indeed powerful, yet strange in the way it solves certain problems. I'm a bit surprised though that most modifiers and operators do not have a counterpart. Relax is one of them. I want to implement it using nodes, but I don't know how to access the neighbor vertices, needed to compute a new position for a relaxed vertex.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3):

The topology nodes are presented in 3.4 version. Using that nodes, you can build a setup like this one:

[image]
[image]

Basically, this 4 nodes gets neighboring vertex position:

[image]

[image]