# Improving an Iterative Shrinkwrap Node in Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, shrinkwrap

Right now I am trying to create an iterative Shrinkwrap Modifier, to achieve two goals:

1. Displacing the middle of an otherwise plain Grid according to 3D Scanned Forms, to create some VDM Texture (subtracting the plain Grid Position from the displaced one to get displacement info, to later use that on other meshes, related to here:  [Using VDM Brushes procedurally in Geometry Nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/294186/using-vdm-brushes-procedurally-in-geometry-nodes) )
2. Shrinkwrapping the same roundcube around many different 3D Scans to later mix/morph between these forms, as they all have the same Indices.

I understand that there is no one fits all solution and the scanned forms can be very different, but the approach in the blend-File below works ok for some of them.

The biggest problem is that it relies on the Grid/Cube iteratively searching the nearest point while getting closer, and doesn’t want to get in the Nooks and Crannies of the Scans, as there is always a nearer point on the surface than in those deep areas.

[image: Original Scan]

[image: Shrinkwrapped Grid, which streches and doesn't get in the tight spots]

[image: Shrinkwrapped roundcube, glitchyness in the concave parts]

The easiest way would be having a „weighted proximity“ (like in find shortest Edge Path), where if most of the Grid already conforms to the Scan, the parts that have a greater Distance from the Grid are favored. But I don’t know if and how its possible to hack something like that.

One approach was to raycast from the (negative) Grid Normals and displace according to the Hit Distance. But in my tests it was very prone to glitches, dealing with false hits, no hits and the transitions between.

Another approach was to change the 3D-Scan from simple/bloated to more complex over iterations, to gradually guide the Mesh to the right places.
Remeshing via Mesh to Volume > Volume to Mesh and blurring the Position, upping the detail every Iteration. I haven’t found a sweet spot yet where the result looks better than my original Shrinkwrap, so maybe this is also a dead end.

Furthermore, it would be neat to have a Relax (?) Function to even out the space of the Grid points after every Iteration. I tried the Relax Mesh Node that @crantisz created here
( [Relax vertices in Geometry Nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/278619/relax-vertices-in-geometry-nodes) ). It seems to somehow work with the Grid, but not with the Cube. Maybe I misunderstood what Relax means, I want the Form to change only minimal, while sliding the points to the places with most stretching. Do you have any tipps how to make that work? Otherwise the Points start to gather at the highest points, which I can only counteract with blurring, at the cost of precision.

I am already quite happy that it works okay and see a lot of creative potential, but if I could fix these issues it would be great and could also serve as a clean Quad Remesh Option.

The .blend-File:

The 3D-Scans in the blend-file are already remeshed low poly and have no textures, to keep the file size small, but it works with detailed meshes too.
The Shrinkcube is the newest version, the Shrinkgrid was from an older file.
The Mix Models Nodegroup morphs between two forms and the Image Textures sampled from their respective original models. Only works when the Iterations for both Objects are the same.
[image: Mixing between Shapes]
Careful with upping the Iterations as there is a Subdiv Node in the Repeat Zone! The Ping-Pong Node sets after how many Iterations it subdivides.

EDIT: While the first Set Position in the Repeat Zone doesn't break the models in these two cases, in many others it does, it can then just be muted.

3D Models used: https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/reishi-mushroom-ab74ec90a0ed41a99b45d67ebc1ee3d3
https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/japanese-rhinoceros-beetle-larva-b67fb6cbe3fa455c81373aaa9f91fa1a

Thanks to anyone who has some Input or can point me in the right direction,

best wishes,

Todesdigga

[image]

Comment: I've been working on something like this myself.. starting with a spherified target ..my iteration step: [de-spherify target a bit, source captures closest UV coordinate on target,  de-spherify target more, shrink source pos a bit to new target pos at captured UV coordinate, blur source pos, less with each iteration].. trying to get the source to follow the target to its completely de-spherified state. Looking for a shrinkwrap with undercuts, evenly spread topo. If I get anywhere, will share.. all suggestions welcome.

Comment: @RobinBetts Uuuh interesting! 
Do I understand you correctly that in the first step you gradually smooth out and "bloat" the Target Object to get closest to the roundcube shape of the Source?
How is that possible? I tried a combination of remeshing, scaling Normals, Blurring and Normalizing Position... 
Do you use Raycast or only Sample Nearest?
Can't wrap my head around the UV part. Would love to see it, thanks for your answer!

Comment: I go all the way.. normalizing to a sphere.. bring it in gradually, and try to coax the source to follow.. ok but not answer-worthy so far.